# Angular XSRF Protection: header not getting added

Tags: angular, csrf, csrf-protection

I'm trying to implement CSRF protection in my angular 4 app. In app.module I have added

```
import: [
HttpClientXsrfModule.withOptions({
 cookieName: 'XSRF-COOKIE',
 headerName: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN',
}),
```

and on my first GET request I am setting  the cookie after a successful response in my component

```
document.cookie = "XSRF-COOKIE=23432434243242342342";
```

However, the X-XSRF-TOKEN header is not added to any of my subsequent HTTP requests (according to chromes network tab request headers section).

From the documentation this seems like it should be automatic. Am I missing something?

https://v4.angular.io/guide/http#security-xsrf-protection

Comment: From the link you provided: *By default, an interceptor sends this cookie on all mutating requests (POST, etc.) to relative URLs but not on GET/HEAD requests or on requests with an absolute URL.*.

Comment: where you are setting the cookie value and when? can you update the post with that information

Comment: @serpent5 Does that mean it would not work for hitting my restful endpoints that are at a different domain, and therefore absolute?

Comment: @Aravind Updated

Comment: @Anthony did you get to solve this ? I have the same problem.